# Radius and strength sliders in pie menus

Tags: python, scripting, texture-painting

How do I add the sliders (radius, strength)in texpaint to a pie menu ?

Comment: You might try looking at Pitiwazou's pie menus, and consider this post as a clue https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?348496-Addon-Wazou-s-Pie-Menus&p=2792716&viewfull=1#post2792716

Comment: Possibly answer your question here then with an example of working code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link as it may help others to see it directly - borrowed from Pitiwazou's post on Blenderartists.org:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    pie = layout.menu_pie()

    ups = context.tool_settings.unified_paint_settings
    sculpt = context.tool_settings.sculpt

    col = pie.column(align=True)        
    col.prop(ups, "size", text="Radius", slider=False)


    col = pie.column(align=True)        
    col.operator("sculpt.sample_detail_size", text="", icon='EYEDROPPER')
    col.prop(sculpt, "constant_detail")
```

Comment: Thank you, I was going to answer with the code but I was away for some time.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it, this is an opportunity to tell the best way to go: shortcuts exist on the keyboard by default for Radius and Strength already. F key to toggle mouse movement to adjust the radius, and Shift-F to adjust the strength - and if using a texture in the brush, use Ctrl-F to rotate the texture brush and Ctrl-Alt-F to rotate the texture mask. Using these, you get a direct on screen feedback that you don't get just from adjusting a slider even in a pie menu in 3d view.